# UIViewController loses track of property

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, snapshot

In my first ViewController having property

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView* snapShotView;
```

And I call

```
self.snapShotView = [[UIScreen mainScreen] snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:YES];
[self.view addSubview: self.snapShotView];
```

Then I present two viewcontrollers on top of it and dismiss them again. When I am back on the first viewController the snapShotView property is empty, but the view still displays. I want to remove the snapShotView, but I no longer have a reference.

If I only display one ViewController on top of the first ViewController and dismiss it, the property still references the correct view. If I present and dismiss another view on top of it, the property is null once the additional two ViewControllers are dismissed.

How can I reference and remove the snapshoView?

Comment: where is this code running? `self.snapShotView = [[UIScreen mainScreen] snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:YES];` in `viewWillAppear`?

Comment: hide your snapshotview on click of back button

Comment: The code runs in a method that after I created and before I  present the first ViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is really strange that you are loosing the reference to subView, but anyway if you are loosing the reference to subView and because of that if you are not able to remove the subView you added and if that's your problem, I'll say you don't need the reference to remove the subView from view :)

You can do something like this :)

```
[[self.view subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

This statement will remove all the subViews from your view without reference :)

and in case you have multiple views added to your view and want to remove just a specific view make use of tags :)

```
self.snapShotView = [[UIScreen mainScreen] snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:YES];
self.snapShotView.tag = someValue;
[self.view addSubview: self.snapShotView];
```

and while removing

```
for (UIView *view in [self.view subviews]) {
     if (view.tag == someValue) {
          [view removeFromSuperview];
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm.